# Why file_get_contents() error on protocol gs (dev local GAE)

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I dev app engine on local.Connect Google cloud storage.Code on app engine i can use file_get_contents(gs://) to get content from google cloud storage.But I dev on local I can't use it.

> Error file_get_contents(gs://..../fees/test-1.png): failed to open
>   stream:
>   "\google\appengine\ext\cloud_storage_streams\CloudStorageStreamWrapper::stream_open"
>   call failed .

Comment: From the error, it seems you are using your GCS Object Link for gsutil in your PhP function, instead of using the GCS Object's Link URL. This [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cloud-console#_accessing) on the section "A user granted access to an object" explains in detail how to access your contents via the Link URL. The GCS Object Link for gsutil should be used within a gsutil environment. I believe it worked for your App Engine application because GAE can still be considered to be within the gsutil environment.

Comment: We will go ahead to add this comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error, it seems you are using your GCS Object Link for gsutil in your PhP function, instead of using the GCS Object's Link URL. This [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cloud-console#_accessing) on the section "A user granted access to an object" explains in detail how to access your contents via the Link URL. The GCS Object Link for gsutil should be used within a gsutil environment. I believe it worked for your App Engine application because GAE can still be considered to be within the gsutil environment.